# Automate Password on Bastion Host?

Tags: bash, for-loop, openssh, iterm2

My New Job requires me to gather some info from thousands of servers. However they have no sshkey setup. Everything is linked to LDAP password.

Setup is
{ Mac using ITerm2 } -->ssh with LDAP+2fA --> Bastion Host --> Connect to all servers but only with LDAP Password.

I dont want to keep typing LDAP passwords for each host I am trying to login. I am non-privilege user on Bastion Host. I cannot Install anything on Bastion like sshpass,expect,plink,

How to Automate entering password with below script with ssh options either in the script itself or Can we use Iterm to autofill when it prompts for password ?

```
#!/bin/bash

inFile=$1
user="zaib"

ssh_options="-o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"

read -r -d "" commands << EOF

#My Commands Here

uname -a;

netstat -rn;


EOF
log="remote_cmd_$inFile"

((c=1))
for srv in $(cat $inFile | awk -F, '{print $1}'); do
    echo -n "$c: $srv " | tee -a $log
    nohup ssh -qtt $ssh_options  $user@$srv "sudo --bash -c '$commands'" 2>&1 | tee -a $log
    ((c=$c+1))
 done
```

Comment: I can't help you with Bastion, but expect is a scripting language so you don't have to install it on a Bastion machine. If you have a Linux server that has expect on it, you're good to go. It seems that sudo might be a problem.

Comment: I tried the to check for accessing binaries but they were not installed

Comment: If you don't have a non-bastion Linux server available to install sources on, perhaps you can compile sshpass statically and copy it to one server. In that case you can invoke sshpass from your home directory and omit installing it as root. (I expect that Bastion doesn't really differ from a "normal" Linux OS).